# Spring Data query from method doesn't recognize column

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I am using Spring Data, I have created my entities wrapped inside of an "AbstractEntity" which all objects extend to get basic columns

AbstractEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date CreatedDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        UpdatedDate = CreatedDate = new Date();
    }

...
```

And my Object/Entity

```
@Entity
public class Trade extends AbstractEntity {
```

When I attempt to use my repository to create a method to `findByCreatedDateAfter(Date date)`

I get an exception that the column can't be found...?

```
public interface TradeRepository extends CrudRepository<Trade, Long>{

    public List<Trade> findByCreatedDateAfter(Date date);
}
```

It compiles (if I use certain capitolization) but than attempting to map the query, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the given name [createdDate] on this ManagedType [streaming.data.AbstractEntity]
```

I also would like to return the `sum(amount)` of one of the amount column for this period.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query derivation mechanism requires standard Java property naming conventions to be applied. There's no property `createdDate` as it's called `CreatedDate` in your class.

To customize the mapping to a certain column, use the `@Column` annotation (hence the name).

Comment: Interesting so I followed the naming convention strategy I saw in the [Spring Boot DATA JPA example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples). Changing `CreatedDate` to `createdDate` in the `abstract object` did the trick.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to the domain classes in the example that use capitalized property names?